# jboss app context-root sub domain config confusion

Tags: apache, jboss, apache2, jboss7.x, mod-jk

I have an app on a subdomain, I wish to access like so:

http://sub.domain.com/myApp/some.jsp

I've tried various config options and I'm close, as JBoss returns 404s, but can't load as expected. JBoss 7.1.1, apache2.

**jboss-web.xml:**

```
<jboss-web>
   <virtual-host>sub.domain.com</virtual-host>
   <context-root>/myApp</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

**jboss' standalone.xml:**

```
<virtual-server name="sub.domain.com" default-web-module="myApp">
    <alias name="sub.domain.com/myApp"/>
    <access-log prefix="myApp-" rotate="true">
        <directory path="server.log"/>
    </access-log>
</virtual-server>
```

**apache conf:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName sub.domain.com
    ServerAlias sub.domain.com
    JkMount /myApp jk
    JKMount /myApp/* jk
</VirtualHost>
```

**workers.properties:**

```
worker.list=jk
worker.jk.port=8009
worker.jk.host=localhost
worker.jk.type=ajp13
worker.jk.mount=/myApp/*
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got it! I was doing too much before. Here is how it's done.

**jboss-web.xml:**
Commented out all those settings above.

**jboss' standalone.xml:**
Removed the virtual-server above, updated the default-host with an alias.

```
<virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="true">
    <alias name="localhost"/>
    <alias name="sub.domain.com"/>
</virtual-server>
```

**apache conf:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    JkMount /myApp/* jk
</VirtualHost>
```

**workers.properties:**

```
worker.list=jk
worker.jk.port=8009
worker.jk.host=localhost
worker.jk.type=ajp13
```

Alright!

Comment: do we need add mod_jk.so file to the apache servre?